# Varargs and argument less method

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I am just catching up with java 1.5, (yes i know its too early;) ) . while trying out few exercises on varargs , i just found something strange as below. the code compiles well and the varargs method is invoked only when i supply atleast one parameter. shouldn't this have been compiler error, a method and overloaded method with varargs. Or is there any specific usecase you may think, this scenario will
 be useful

```
public class VarargsExample {
    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        test1();
    }

    public static void test1(int... x) {
        System.out.println("AssertionExample.test1(ARRAY METHOD)");
    }

    public static void test1() {
        System.out.println("AssertionExample.test1(PARAM LESS)");
    }

}
```

PS: tried to search this in SO, could not find similar one. pardon me if there is one already:)

Summary, thanks all for your quick responses. seems to be the normal methods are the one preferred. Same is the case when a single param method is present as below

```
public class VarargsExample{  
 public static void main( String args[] ){  


  test1(); 
  test1(2); 
 } 

 public static  void test1(int... x){
     System.out.println("AssertionExample.test1(ARRAY METHOD)");
 }

 public static  void test1(int x){
     System.out.println("AssertionExample.test1(single param METHOD)");
 }

 public static void test1(){
     System.out.println("AssertionExample.test1(PARAM LESS)");
 } 

}
```

Comment: @Pshemo thank you for formatting the code .

Comment: What makes you think this should fail?

Comment: @christopher i never said it will fail.

Comment: No problem. BTW based on lack of arguments `test1()` is more precise than `test1(int... x)` so I don't think of any reason why compiler shouldn't use it over varargs...

Comment: precise? how so . If that is the case , then the very purpose of varargs seem to be lost . dont you think ?

Comment: @Ravisha: Non-vararg methods are "preferred" to vararg methods by the compiler. As soon as you add the first int argument to the method call, the vararg version is called. Vararg methods can be extremely useful in case you don't know the exact number of arguments you want to use. Example: [Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-)

Comment: Its looks like PARAM LESS method getting preference over ARRAY METHOD when no arguments supplied, but if we comment the  PARAM LESS method then ARRAY METHOD will get called. The same happens if you define  `public static void test1(int b)`  this method gets called when explicit single argument is proivded.

Comment: Just remember, when multiple methods are valid for a given method call, the method with *varargs* parameters are considered **last**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of call, the parameter-less overloading gets called because its signature is more specific than that of the overlauding with varargs. It is in general a very bad idea to have two overloaded methods which perform a completely different operation. So let's assume that the parameter-less method does the same thing as the varargs method when called without arguments, that is, the parameter-less method is a specialization of the varargs method.

Then a use-case is the following. Calling a varargs method always requires creating an array. Although, certainly at first, I wouldn't think about such minor optimizations too much, but it is an overhead which might, in some cases (for example in tight loop), be considerable enough. The parameter-less version of the method does not require creating an array, and additionally also may contain other optimizations for the specific case.

Sometimes, one sees more than one specializations, one with no arguments, one with one, one with two, and a general method. For example:

```
void doSomething() { ... }
void doSomething(String a1) { ... }
void doSomething(String a1, String a2) { ... }
void doSomething(String... as) { ... }
```

But I suggest to only do this in a late stage of development, if at all.